# jquery: how do I trigger an event after a click-hold-release action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a menu after a click, drag, and release action.

How do I trigger that with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Listen for a `mousedown` event on whatever should be clicked on.
2. Add a `mousemove` and `mouseup` event handler to the `window`
3. In the `mouseup` event handler call `trigger('yourcustomeventhere')` on whatever element you please. Also, remove the `mouseup` and `mousemove` event handlers from `window`
4. ...?
5. profit.

jQuery is the library that will do this for you. I thought I explained the code well enough, but apparantly not:

```
$(anElement).mousedown(foodown);

function foodown(){
  $(window).mousemove(foomove).mouseup(fooup);
  //stuff
}

function foomove(){
  //stuff
}

function fooup(){
  $(someElement).trigger('yourcustomevent');
  $(window).unbind('mousemove', foomove).unbind('mouseup', fooup);
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Dragondrop jQuery plugin by zzzzBov
 */
(function ($) {
  "use strict";
  var $window;

  function begin(e) {
    var event;
    $window.mousemove(drag).mouseup(end);
    event = $.Event('beginDragon');
    $(e.target).trigger(event);
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  function drag(e) {
    var event;
    event = $.Event('dragDragon');
    $(e.target).trigger(event);
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  function end(e) {
    var event;
    event = $.Event('endDragon');
    $(e.target).trigger(event);
    $window.unbind('mousemove', drag).unbind('mouseup', end);
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  $.each('beginDragon dragDragon endDragon'.split(' '), function (i, name) {
    $.fn[name] = function(data,fn) {
      if (fn == null) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
      }
      return arguments.length > 0 ?
        this.bind(name, data, fn) :
        this.trigger(name);
    };
  });

    $window = $(window);
    $window.mousedown(begin);
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I know this. Is there a library that will do this for me? there is jQuery's drag and drop stuff... but I'm not sure if I can have it do nothing until the mouseup event

Comment: @TheLindyHop, eventually you'll have to write some code no matter what library you use. I personally think the little bit of code necessary to do this is as good as it needs to be. I suppose I could extract it into a dragondrop plugin of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQueryUI and let it do a lot for you. It also comes with a create UI (of course, because it's jQuery UI)

Take a look at this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

edit:

Or take a look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
Take a close look to the events used here.

Comment: not quite what I'm looking for. everything in that demo is instant.

Comment: jQuery just does draggable objects. I just want a menu to .show() after a click-drag-release event. =\

Comment: but, I don't want to drag any objects. If there is a way to get the end event of a drag, though, that would be useful =\

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has a [drag](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [drop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) implementation. If that doesn't do what you do, you'll have to roll your own implementation by tracking the [`mouseup`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) and [`mousedown`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) events on the element yourself. (And possibly [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) to detect if the mouse left the area you want to track the gesture in.)