# Native javascript equivalent to jQuery.draggable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

Is there a native javascript code equivalent to jQuery's draggable?
I don't need all the features but

1. being able to drag a modal window from a handle.
2. on start and on end
   events as I need to make an overlay layer while dragging to prevent
   the mouse being upon the iframe inside the modal window.
3. there will be only one draggable item on the document.

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/ Why don't you want to use jquery?

Comment: sure, the equivalent is.. write it. or for 120k just include it to your website and go to lunch. Honestly, what is the question here? Can someone write me some great code which I already know where to find and is totally free but would rather not use?

Comment: No jQuery at all, or just no `jQuery.draggable`?  It's going to be quite complex for full browser support with no jQuery at all; if you can use straight jQ, use `.mousedown()` and `.mouseup()` and `.mousemove()`.  Store the start `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` values along with the starting dialog position, and use the deltas to move stuff around.

Comment: @Jere I'm injecting my script on a document I dont have any control on. It already has JQ loaded but draggable doesn't work with that version. So I tried to load JQ again and it breaks some existing scripts.

Comment: @NRohler Just no draggable. JQ is there.

Comment: Don't you need [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.2/Draggable) in addition to jQuery for `.draggable()` to work (with jQuery, not native JS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the events `dragstart` and `dragend`. Tie the position of the modal relevant to the mouse's x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There is the HTML5 dnd api, but since nobody i've talked to liked it in any way and none of the older browsers support it,I would say you found a good solution in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 methods which seem cleaner than jQuery's:

```
<div draggable="true"
  ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', '12345')">
drag me
</div>

<div ondragover="return false;" 
  ondrop="this.innerHTML=event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')">
drop on me
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Although the question states native JavaScript, I'm going to respond given that @Moe Sweet commented that jQuery *was* enabled.

Drag and drop is a particular event chain. It's not obscenely difficult, but it can be challenging.

Simply put, drag and drop is the following steps/events:

1. Mouse pressed down, dragging is enabled
2. Mouse is moved, dragging continues
3. Mouse is let up, dragging is disabled

The simple solution is to use those events: `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup`

```
$(anElement).mousedown(foodown);

function foodown(){
  $(window).mousemove(foomove).mouseup(fooup);
  //stuff
}

function foomove(){
  //stuff
}

function fooup(){
  //stuff
  $(window).unbind('mousemove', foomove).unbind('mouseup', fooup);
}
```

A point that should be noticed is that the events following the `mousedown` need to be bound to the `window` so that they are caught if the mouse has left the original element while being held down.

The "stuff" part of the code is where you'll need to check the screen coords of the element vs the screen coords of the mouse and move things appropriately. Motion is only really necessary during the `mousemove` event as the mouse wont have moved for a `mouseup` or `mousedown` event.

[There is a similar question where I posted my code for a jQuery.dragondrop plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587846/jquery-how-do-i-trigger-an-event-after-a-click-hold-release-action).